# Convert string(Dec/2018) to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a date column in pandas like the following as string datatype:

```py
df['Date]

Dec/2018
Mar/2017
Sep/2019
```

I want the date column in pandas like the following as `datetime datatype`, 
 `not string datatype`:

```py
df['Date]

`December-2018`
`March-2017`
`September-2019`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd


# define sample data to create a dataframe from
data = {'Date': ['Dec/2018', 'Mar/2017', 'Sep/2019']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


# define a function to convert dates
def format_date(el):
    return datetime.strptime(el, '%b/%Y').strftime('%B-%Y')


# apply conversion to desired column and store output in new column
df['Date_formatted'] = df['Date'].apply(format_date)


# print the dataframe to check result
print(df)
```

Which will output the dataframe as this:

```
       Date  Date_formatted
0  Dec/2018   December-2018
1  Mar/2017      March-2017
2  Sep/2019  September-2019
```

Answer (score 1):

The `pandas` approach using [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%b/%Y').dt.strftime('%B-%Y')
```

---

```
0     December-2018
1        March-2017
2    September-2019
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
x = datetime.date.today()
print(x.strftime("%B - %Y "))
```

1. For additional information, you can read [this](https://stackabuse.com/how-to-format-dates-in-python/).
2. I hope it will help you.